# Why there is no EPSG code in ArcMap?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, boundless-suite

In Arcmap, when you right click on the layer >> go to properties >> select source tab there you see the properties of projection.

I cannot understand why ESRI did not managed to add SRID EPSG in their software's ? I mean I know the details are important but the role of software is to  simplify and not to complicate !! Correct me if i am wrong.

I came across this custom projection . i tried to find out the id using this [site](http://prj2epsg.org/)  but it says ..

[image]

What should i do ??

Comment: This sounds more like a rant and not a question.  **Do you have a question??**  If you have a question like this about ESRI software, you will probably get a better answer out of your sales representative.

Comment: yes i am annoyed but tell me do you really think sales can answer it ?? Its the core professionals who understands the software in and out can answer this question.

Comment: Yes, but it is client demand that typically drives development, and it is usually sales people who deal with clients and have more say in what customers are wanting.

Comment: You're looking at a summary page.  The details are present when you describe the feature class from the **Catalog** window.  If you want EPSG codes in the layer summary, I suggest you go to ideas.esri.com, and write a somewhat less strident enhancement request, giving a business case for such a change.  Still this isn't really a question for GIS SE.

Comment: It can well be that there is no EPSG code for Transverse Mercator having Central meridian at 78.5 degrees and latitude of origin at 11 degrees. This feels like a custom made system. Oh, just noticed that you wrote yourself that it is a custom projection. So no reason at all to accuse ESRI nor EPSG in this case.

Comment: maybe you can re-word the question to ask 'where can i find the EPSG value of my data in ArcMap'?

Comment: As @user30184 mentioned, there is no EPSG code that matches the projection parameters as given, even using a different geographic CRS. Disclosure: I work for Esri and I'm part of the group that maintains the EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry.

Comment: Abhijit, why do you need an SRID/WKID? Are you trying to publish a WMS or other map service?

Comment: And if you need to use your data in some external system with EPSG code you can reproject data into some other CRS that has the code. Your .prj is still totally understandable for ArcMap and probably for GDAL, QGIS etc. as well because all the necessary parameters are defined. May be that GeoServer or MapServer could use the data even without re-projecting. Better possibilities with MapServer by defining the projection with Proj4 strings.

Comment: @AbhijitGujar maybe the real answer to this question is that ArcGIS users don't really need to know the EPSG code of their coordinate systems because all the information they are used to knowing, thus all they need to know, is in the existing dialogue boxes. When did we all start thinking about EPSG codes? When we started using other spatial software like PostGIS and QGIS... if you're looking to make ArcGIS more like these systems, perhaps this is better left alone (see comments from ESRI staff below...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place I've been able to find it is in the Data Frame Properties > Coordinate System tab under the Current Coordinate System definition:

[image]

Comment: If you look at the data's property page via ArcCatalog, it's listed there as well. As the OP pointed out, we don't include it on the Source tab of a layer in ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks  Vince for the idea to put this in idea esri i will do that when i will get time .

Comment: Thanks mKennedy , I am glad that some one from core group such as Geodetic Parameter Registry (ESRI) came forward . I would really appreciate that .

Comment: Thanks user30184 for pointing out the exact parameter. No i did not write it up myself i got that from client. Well i am not so expert to make custom projection. thanks :).

Comment: Thanks mapBaker for re-pharase suggestion i will do it .

Comment: Well  Branco .. now you see what i mean . Thanks for joining in the disscussion .

Comment: To summarize .... What i want do is to suggest and spread the idea of adding EPSG code in ESRI software . It will surely help millions of user ...

Comment: But Esri is already using EPSG codes extensively, and they **can't**, by definition, be used with custom coordinate systems.